# Contentful query content type and filter on reference (multiple)

Tags: contentful

Within Contentful i have the content type "post". The post can have multiple categories (another content type). Now i'm trying to query the posts but filter them on category. My query looks something like this:

`https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$space/entries?access_token=$token&include=3&fields.categories.fields.slug=features&limit=3&skip=0&content_type=post`

The error returned:
`You are trying to search on a reference to an unsupported type. You can only search on references to single entries`

So basically i can only reference 1 category, but i need many not only in this use case but on a lot more. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could flip the query around and ask for entries that link to a certain category.

```
curl --include \
 --request GET \
 https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/$SPACE_ID/environments/master/entries?access_token=$TOKEN&links_to_entry=7fYxxN67JKyUiYuE4Cq8sI&content_type=post
```

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/links-to-entry

Comment: Thanks will give this a try after the weekend, will update if it works

Comment: What about multiple linked entries? Let's say i want to filter on category & tag

Comment: I think you'd have to make two calls then. :) Assuming you mean that you have a content type `tag` and another one `category`.

Comment: Exactly, that kind of sucks but thanks for the answer!